How can I find out if there is a Ubuntu support group near me?
I'm installing Ubuntu on donated laptops for distribution to people who need them and now & then I run into installation problems on certain hardware. How do I find out if there is a local Ubuntu support or interest group near me?

There is a page for that: Ubuntu locos team. Direct link to the continents and countries.
There is also a Discourse for locos teams.

and now & then I run into installation problems on certain hardware

Best place though is to ask on AskUbuntu itself: do a search on hardware (model, chipset and the likes). Often enough to find a solution. Or at least a "why" as some hardware just needs to be avoided and then some that do work but need tinkering.
